# Link different CIFS mounts of different users to the same location

Tags: mount, users, symlink, cifs

Many users on the client each have personal CIFS password-protected mounts to the server in their respective home folder. E.g.,

```
/home/user1/server/share1 (mounted with credentials for user1)
/home/user1/server/share2 (mounted with credentials for user1)
/home/user2/server/share1 (mounted with credentials for user2)
/home/user2/server/share2 (mounted with credentials for user2)
...
```

It would be much nicer if every user could access their respective mounts on 
`/mnt/server/share1`, `/mnt/server/share2`.

Can this be accomplished? (I was thinking personalized symbolic links might be a solution, if something link this exists on Unix.)

Answer (score 0):

*AutoFS* can be solution 
see more under this tutorial https://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs

Or add sudoers mount for cifs and leave users to mount their own stuf on their own with shader creds.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/67405/auto-mounting-network-shares-per-user

Comment: Would it be helpful this solution?